# WPF: How can I disable one button if my window has any validation error?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I have some (>20) controls in a window, each is bound to a property of a ViewModel.

The ViewModel implements `IDataErrorInfo`, in order to do some validations, and it works well.

Now I add a button something like "Commit" to the window. I want to disable the button if any control has validation error.

Although I can use `DataTrigger` to do the trick like this:

```
<Button Content="Commit">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=control1, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=control2, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <!-- DataTriggers for control3, 4, 5... -->
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

That'll be a long XAML code because I have 20+ controls in this window, so I wonder is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should create a command in ViewModel.
Something like this:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ICommand CommitCommand{ get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        CommitCommand = new RelayCommand(Commit, CanCommit);
    }

    private void Commit(object parameter)
    {
        // button click handler
    }

    private bool CanCommit(object parameter)
    {
        // check: view model has errors
    }
}
```

Implement ICommand interface you can get here: [Wpf Tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html)

Xaml code:

```
<Button Command={Binding CommitCommand}/>
```

Comment: Yes, I already have a command bound to the button, but how can I  check view model's errors in `CanCommit` method? Should I check all the properties again?

Comment: Check items or "Error" properties for IDataErrorInfo.

Comment: `IDataErrorInfo.Error` seems to be useless in WPF.

Comment: `IDataErrorInfo.Item` can't help?

Comment: `IDataErrorInfo.Item` works fine, but do I have to check all the properties again? I mean the WPF binding has do the checking stuff already, what I need is just an "ok/ng" flag I can bind to the commit button.

Comment: Yes. Or you can create field `hasErrors` e.g. and change it when calls `Item` property.

Comment: Ok I did it, I use Reflection to enumerate every property and call `this[propertyName]` to check. Maybe it's slow but it works.Thank you @Vlad

Comment: `Bool` field is not enough. You need something like `Dictionary<string /*fieldName*/, bool /*hasError*/>` if you don't want call this method again. It must works faster.